# Permission denied error when reading files in zip folder using python in Django

Tags: python, django, pydicom

I'm trying to read dicom files in a zip folder but when I run this code it gives me this error:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'PATIENT_DICOM/'

```
file = patient.PATIENT_DICOM

with zipfile.ZipFile(file,'r') as zip:
    zip.extractall()
    ls= zip.infolist()
    slices = [pydicom.read_file(s.filename) for s in ls]
```

Comment: I don't think you can directly work on a zipfile this way - you probably have to extract the zip first.

Comment: i used         zip.extractall() but the error is the same

Comment: At what point do you get the exception? Can you add the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to read the extracted DICOM files:

```
zip_path = patient.PATIENT_DICOM
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as zip:
    path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    zip.extractall(path)
    slices = []
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            slices.append(pydicom.dcmread(filepath))
    shutil.rmtree(path)
```

Note that this first extracts all files into a temp dir, which is probably faster than accessing them one by one. This assumes, that all files in the zip belong to the same volume or series. If you want to work with the slices further, you have to sort them properly first, for example by `InstanceNumber`.

Comment: i did it and i got another error    [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\Dell_5G\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpotwe933h\\PATIENT_DICOM'

Comment: At what line does this happen? In `zip.extract`?

Comment: Ok, I changed the code by just extracting all files first - see above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try this:

```py
data = pydicom.dcmread(filename)
```

Comment: `dcmread` is an alias for `read_file`, and while it is correct that it shall be used, it does not change the semantics.